# Typescript how to deal with union types and different attributes

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I need to develop a function that accept 2 type of input.

```js
type InputA = {
 name: string
 content: string
 color: string
}

type InputB = {
 name: string
 content: number
}

type Input = InputA | InputB
```

When I try to implement the function accepting this 2 inputs, I would like to check if the input has the `color` attribute, so I can distinct the 2 types.

However this will lead me to a compiler error:

```js
function foo(input:Input){
 const color = (input.color) ? input.color : undefined;
                  // ^
                  // | Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Input'.
                  // | Property 'color' does not exist on type 'InputB'.
 ...
}
```

I know I can implement a new attribute, like `type_name`, that exists in both types and then check on that one. But I would like to avoid it since I don't like having an extra attribute only for this reason in this particular function.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For type-safety reasons, you can't access properties which might not exist on a union type with the *dot*-notation. Use the `in` operator instead.

```
function foo(input:Input){
  const color = "color" in input ? input.color : undefined
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAglAvFA3gWAFBRwCGAthAFxQDOwATgJZwDm+UAxgPZzATeU0NmrTgBsOtfnUYs8AX3z5QkWAmQAhDNlbEykwTPZcefQohIAjCLXzy8i8NHhJgmp8jQAfFc7UK8AM0Q4NmB6Lih-Dg4ACkZncjdgAEpcAkM4GkMxWk0AIlFxXKhGYtUXAH5S5wA6ApzKIIATCH9GCEabIA)

Answer (score 1):

U can propose another approach to use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) since you can use them for a lot more than the color property once you define the type identification logic.

```js
// tells the typescript whether the variable is of type InputA
const isOfTypeInputA = (input: Input): input is InputA => {
    return input.hasOwnProperty("color");
}

function foo(input:Input){
 const color = isOfTypeInputA(input) ? input.color : undefined;
}
```

Working solution here: [Typescritp playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAglAvFA3gKCnAQwFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLOAczwGMB7OYCD8quxl1gBtW1HjXpMAvjhyhIsBMgBCGbHkIkxfJlDYcuwcnEREARhGo5ps8NHhJgq%208jQAfBQ6Uy9VKLQoA8gBmACq2zqiqABT0DuQRAJTksch%20FB4uGAB8alB5UNQQwIjUcH6KwAB0ABYEgQDucAAK1KyQ1KBRAERswtRdCQDcVjJBiHDMwLTsUEGsrDEVpIm4uuy%20vSKq-sFhkBEoiw4JUAD85Q6Vm9RQ5OMAJhBB9BD3w2twFEIQlcIMUQBya4AgA0az6QxGOB8jgI8QqaEwWHwxDIUC6GggXTBek43HRuIM2PBInIXVMgkQWKgkmGMKgpnhnlUyMxZMxxMJ%20IAbNY5gsCJD%20VFTJCgA)